# How catch system call in JAVA?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, kill, system-calls

I want to catch an exception (or something else) when my program is killed by a `kill` command from the operating system.

I want to print a message to a log file before closing.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I have implemented working example in answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277630/windows-shutdown-hook-on-java-application-run-from-a-bat-script/9277766#9277766) question. Unfortunately, it uses JNI, that not always acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

Comment: you can not catch SIGKILL signal as opposed to SIGTERM.

Comment: This will work in most cases. This will *not* work when killing process with `kill -9` on Unix and may fail when `OutOfMemeoryException` was thrown.