# Killing Java process gracefully using WMIC

Tags: java, windows, powershell, wmic, taskkill

I have to kill a Java process gracefully from windows. The requirement is that there is a Java main class XYZ.java which has a shutdown hook added named ABC.java containing some piece of code.I have to run code present in ABC.java when XYZ.java terminates.

In linux, I am able to do so using 'kill' command.
In windows, I used below command but that's not killing my class gracefully:
WMIC PROCESS where "Name='java.exe' AND CommandLine LIKE '%%XYZ%%'" CALL TERMINATE.However, I am able to achieve this windows by running CTRL+C while running java process XYZ from cmd.

Please suggest.

Comment: Perhaps `taskkill` without `/f` is a better fit

Comment: I tried below specifying PID but that also didn't help: 
  taskkill /PID $startup_pid 
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277630/windows-shutdown-hook-on-java-application-run-from-a-bat-script